Connecting two ros2 nodes throw docker, different host, same network
I'm new setting up ros2 modules and I have the following problem:
I can't connect two ros2 nodes running insde docker from my host (mac) to a raspberry pi.
my local machine is a macOS I'm running the following docker compose:
services:
  ros2_ws:
    image: osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full
    network_mode: host
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - .:/workstation
    working_dir: /workstation
    container_name: workstation_container
    tty: true

Inside this container I can run the basic ros2 node talker and listener then I have a second docker compose on a Raspberry PI like this:
services:
  ros2:
    build: .
    network_mode: host
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - .:/robot_ws
    working_dir: /robot_ws
    container_name: robot_ws_container
    tty: true

and this is the dockerfile I use
# This is an auto generated Dockerfile for ros:ros-base
# generated from docker_images_ros2/create_ros_image.Dockerfile.em
FROM ros:humble-ros-core-jammy

# install bootstrap tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3-colcon-common-extensions \
    python3-colcon-mixin \
    python3-rosdep \
    python3-vcstool \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# bootstrap rosdep
RUN rosdep init && \
  rosdep update --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO

# setup colcon mixin and metadata
RUN colcon mixin add default \
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/colcon/colcon-mixin-repository/master/index.yaml && \
    colcon mixin update && \
    colcon metadata add default \
      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/colcon/colcon-metadata-repository/master/index.yaml && \
    colcon metadata update

# install ros2 packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ros-humble-ros-base=0.10.0-1* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


I can ping correctly from my Mac to the RPi and RPi to Mac but when I start the talker from my Mac and the listener from my RPi, the messages don't go throw.
What sudgestions do you have?
I tried setting up export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=5 on both machines but still not working.
I also tried setting up a network like this but no luck:
services:
  ros2_ws:
    image: osrf/ros:humble-desktop-full
    ports:
      - "11311:11311"
    volumes:
      - /Users/ricardmarsalcastan/Documents/Projects/workstation:/workstation
    working_dir: /workstation
    container_name: workstation_container
    tty: true
    networks:
      - robot_ws_network

networks:
  robot_ws_network:
  name: robot_ws_network
  external: true

